# expected initializer before void arduino

Tags: arduino-due

When I try to compile the following code in Arduino ,I get the error "expected initializer before 'void'".How can I get the code to work?

```
  void setup() {  
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

float area = 0.0f,pre_area = 0.0f,tarea = 0.0f,rarea = 0.0f;
int x = 0,pre_x = 0,t = 0,pre_t = 0;


long unsigned int t


void loop()
{
  x = analogRead(A0);
  t = millis();
  float diff_t = (float)(t - pre_t)/1000.0f;
  area = (0.5 * (pre_x + x) * diff_t) + pre_area;

  Serial.print(area);
  analogWrite(DAC0, area);
  pre_x = x;
  pre_area = area;
  pre_time = t;
}
```

Comment: Now that the question is answered please flag it as answered

Answer (score 1):

You add the semicolon that is missing at the end of `long unsigned int t`

Comment: Amongst other things. ;)

Answer (score 1):

**Why have you written t = 0 here and declared it again below??**

```
int x = 0,pre_x = 0,t = 0,pre_t = 0;
```

**Semi Colon Missing**

```
long unsigned int t;
```

**Where have you declared pre_time??**

```
  pre_time = t;
```

Answer (score 0):

```C++
long unsigned int t
```

No semicolon.

---

Plus, make up your mind what type "t" is:

```C++
int x = 0,pre_x = 0,t = 0,pre_t = 0;
long unsigned int t;
```

Is it `int` or `long unsigned int`?

---

> How can I get the code to work?

Avoid C++ syntax errors.